# I Need Help With Volts And Powering LED Lights

Tags: voltage, led

I'm currently working on a science fair project, were I have to power a LED light bulb with potatoes. I can't find any websites that answer my 2 questions. Luckily I was able to find the answers to most of them. So i'll list them below and hopefully you can answer them.

1. How many volts does it take to power a 120 watt LED light.
2. How does a potato conduct electricity.

Comment: 1) *Any*. 2) Potato is containing water and some acids, making it conductive.

Comment: Google can answer both of those questions. And good luck lighting a 120W lightbulb with potatoes!

Comment: Is it really 120W LED?? It's a little Sun...

Comment: Use potato to operate a switch, 120W only from mains.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Why do you need a potato to operate a switch? Well, if you are that hungry that you can't flip a switch without some potato...

Comment: A 120W LED from a potato battery - don't think so.

Comment: Me? I don't need it. Although, with a potato canon it could be fun.

Comment: chillax and watch some u tube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FITxr6bJmd8

Comment: @Lizzi Is there any chance that it is meant to be a 120 milliwatt LED (120 mW)? To power an LED, it needs a particular current, not voltage. There is a voltage drop across the LED, but it is the current which is important. If the voltage drop was, say, 1.8 V (typical for a red LED), then a 120 W one would take (120 W / 1.8 V) = 66.7 amps. That is a *lot* of current and beyond science fair technology.

Comment: See: https://www.teachengineering.org/activities/view/cub_energy2_lesson04_activity2 Looks like a zinc/copper potato is about 1.5 V. There is internal resistance, so they say "Expect two potatoes in series to be able to light an LED"

Answer (score 1):

What can you expect from a two potato (in series) battery voltage wise?

[image]

The voltage depends on how far the metal electrodes are apart in the **electrochemical series**.

By connecting the potatoes **in series** you can increase the available voltage.

A three potato battery using zinc (or galvanised metal) and copper electrodes should easily light up a red LED.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on the LED, some are in the thirties.
2. By sticking two different types of metals into a potato, you are able to use the conductive materials and acids in the potato to create a flow of electrons from one metal to the other.

120w? You'd probably need hundreds of potatoes in order to even get it to dimly light up for a short time, and thousands if you want it to run at full power...

Either way, since potatoes aren't very good batteries, their current output is low enough so that even if the voltage is a bit over the LED'S max,  the higher current draw feom the led will cause the voltage to drop until the led is consuming what it needs to consume, unless you have a lot of potatoes, then you might burn it.